# node-red html5 streaming video

Tags: video-streaming, node-red

I'm new to both node-red and javascript and I was hoping someone could help me. I have been trying to stream a video using node-red. I have successfully displayed an image using the this flow.

```
[{
    "id": "c2701738.8bfcb",
    "type": "http response",
    "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
    "name": "",
    "statusCode": "",
    "headers": {},
    "x": 1118.170166015625,
    "y": 3207,
    "wires": []
  },

  {
    "id": "4d34db55.ad8834",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
    "name": "Set Content-Type header",
    "func": "msg.headers = { \"Content-Type\":\"image/png\"};\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 882.170166015625,
    "y": 3207,
    "wires": [
      ["c2701738.8bfcb"]
    ]
  }, {
    "id": "21504cc0.71adcc",
    "type": "http in",
    "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
    "name": "",
    "url": "/image1",
    "method": "get",
    "upload": false,
    "swaggerDoc": "",
    "x": 145.17022705078125,
    "y": 3206,
    "wires": [
      ["aa24fb51.7861f"]
    ]
  }, {
    "id": "aa24fb51.7861f",
    "type": "file in",
    "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
    "name": "Picture Selector",
    "filename": "/home/pi/.node-red/lee.png",
    "format": "",
    "sendError": true,
    "x": 596.1702270507812,
    "y": 3207.000244140625,
    "wires": [
      ["4d34db55.ad8834"]
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried this flow to stream a video.

```
[{
  "id": "47af46de.9382d8",
  "type": "http in",
  "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
  "name": "",
  "url": "/video3",
  "method": "get",
  "upload": false,
  "swaggerDoc": "",
  "x": 139,
  "y": 3369,
  "wires": [
    ["9da4e018.797ce8"]
  ]
}, {
  "id": "f7318675.c876a",
  "type": "function",
  "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
  "name": "Set Content-Type header",
  "func": "msg.headers = { \"Content-Type\":\"video/mp4\"};\nreturn msg;",
  "outputs": 1,
  "noerr": 0,
  "x": 869.9999389648438,
  "y": 3370,
  "wires": [
    ["2e33de98.3a55da"]
  ]
}, {
  "id": "2e33de98.3a55da",
  "type": "http response",
  "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
  "name": "",
  "statusCode": "",
  "headers": {},
  "x": 1110.9999389648438,
  "y": 3371,
  "wires": []
}, {
  "id": "9da4e018.797ce8",
  "type": "file in",
  "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
  "name": "Video Selector",
  "filename": "/home/pi/.node-red/1.mp4",
  "format": "stream",
  "sendError": false,
  "x": 592,
  "y": 3369.000244140625,
  "wires": [
    ["f7318675.c876a"]
  ]
}]
```

and this one too.

```
[{
  "id": "28aa7076.b2c0e",
  "type": "http in",
  "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
  "name": "",
  "url": "/video4",
  "method": "get",
  "upload": false,
  "swaggerDoc": "",
  "x": 145,
  "y": 3525,
  "wires": [
    ["898878ed.61ff48"]
  ]
}, {
  "id": "866daf6f.5eb068",
  "type": "http response",
  "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
  "name": "",
  "statusCode": "",
  "headers": {},
  "x": 874.5,
  "y": 3528,
  "wires": []
}, {
  "id": "a1babcbf.9ecac8",
  "type": "template",
  "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
  "name": "",
  "field": "payload",
  "fieldType": "msg",
  "format": "handlebars",
  "syntax": "mustache",
  "template": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n\n<video width=\"640\" height=\"480\" autoplay>\n  <source src=\"{{msg.payload}}\" type=\"video/mp4\">\n  Your browser does not support the video tag.\n</video>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n\n",
  "output": "str",
  "x": 732,
  "y": 3528,
  "wires": [
    ["866daf6f.5eb068"]
  ]
}, {
  "id": "898878ed.61ff48",
  "type": "file in",
  "z": "6a1a7f76.b846d8",
  "name": "videoSelector",
  "filename": "/home/pi/.node-red/1.mp4",
  "format": "stream",
  "sendError": true,
  "x": 483,
  "y": 3528,
  "wires": [
    ["a1babcbf.9ecac8"]
  ]
}]
```

Both of the video flows throw a "No response object" message.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the stream mode with `http-in` and `http-response` nodes because in this mode the `file-in` node creates new messages for each chunk of the file.

Try the `buffer` mode.

Comment: Using the file node in Node-Red only gives me the following choices:a single utf8 string, a msg per line, a single Buffer object and a stream of Buffers. I tried

Comment: using both Buffer options. The single Buffer Object doesn't do anything. The page just continues to load and never stop and shows no messages. The stream of Buffers is the one that gives the "No response object" message.

Comment: You can not use stream of buffers. The single buffer should work. How big is the video and what does the network tab in the browser developer tools say?